# cleaning up downloaded .tmp files when using FileStream after cancelling download

Tags: c#, winforms, frameworks

I'm using the FileStream class from System.IO in the .net Framework (4.8) to download a file and store the blocks in a tmp file. The file is downloaded through the SendAsync method from HttpClient. I pass a cancellation token to this method. I have checked that the cancellation token is created and is the same instance on which the actual cancel action ( _cancellationToken.Cancel() ) is called.

After cancelling the download I trigger a finally block which should cleanup the .tmp file which is left behind. This action throws a file in use error which is not completely illogical. However I need to remove these files in order to make it possible to re-download the file on user request.

Is there a way to (force) the unlocking of the .tmp file and clean it up?